# Thread doesn't execute the function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I have written two functions which they can kill a process by its name. You can specify the name of a process, and after the execution of the program, that process will kill.

These two functions are working fine, but when I decided to run them via threads, they didn't execute. What is the problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

BOOL TerminateMyProcess(DWORD dwProcessId, UINT uExitCode)
{
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_TERMINATE;
    BOOL  bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, uExitCode);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return result;
}

DWORD GetProcessList()
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD dwPriorityClass;

    // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return(FALSE);
    }

    // Set the size of the structure before using it.
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    // Retrieve information about the first process,
    // and exit if unsuccessful
    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);  // clean the snapshot object
        return(FALSE);
    }

    // Now walk the snapshot of processes 
    do
    {
        std::string str(pe32.szExeFile);

        if (str == "notepad.exe") // put the name of your process you want to kill
        {
            TerminateMyProcess(pe32.th32ProcessID, 1);
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    return(TRUE);
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadingOne(LPVOID arg_param) {
    return GetProcessList();
}

auto main(int argc, const char* argv[]) -> decltype(0)
{
    DWORD ThreadId;
    HANDLE ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadingOne, (LPVOID)0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &ThreadId);
    ResumeThread(ThreadHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

The thread function didn't start anyway. I didn't know what is the mistake with this threading. I should mention here, I just started multithreading earlier, so it is maybe a simple question but I am a newbie in threads world.

Comment: I'm not sure about Windows, but you start the process then immediately return from the `main` function which exits the running process which on many other systems would terminate *all* running threads in the process. Are you sure this doesn't happen here as well?

Comment: How difficult, in c++11 with `std::thread`, you are responsible for joining the thread. So that the program waits until it's finished. Does a similar call exist in the native API?

Comment: And while the code you show is indeed a [mcve], perhaps it's a little bit *to* minimal? Because with the code as you currently show it there's really no need for a thread.

Comment: you exit from self process before new thread start. and what sense create thread suspended and then resume it ?

Comment: @JVApen - *Does a similar call exist in the native API* of course exist (how interesting this done in c++ lib if not exist ?!) and much more and better variants compare very poor с++ opportunities. and i be not say that use *std::thread* more easy compare `CreateThread`. in all case less efficient and have restrictions

Comment: @RbMm it could be implicit in the Close call?

Comment: @JVApen - in windows we can wait for single or multiple objects, including threads. can not wait thread exit, but instead some "signal" set by thread. many variants exist, compare poor с++ opportunities (join). also std::thread say can not be called from dll entry point, some critical sections. when CreateThread can. and `std::thread` very not efficient call (serious overhead) compare native call

Comment: I think what's needed here is a call to `WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, INFINITE);` just before the `return 0;` line in `main()`.  Otherwise your program exits, probably before the thread has a chance to execute.

Comment: I confirm: your code works fine if you put `WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, INFINITE);` just after `ResumeThread`.

Comment: You can simplify by calling like this: `HANDLE ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadingOne, (LPVOID)0, 0, &ThreadId);` (`0` instead of `CREATE_SUSPENDED`) and drop the call to `ResumeThread`  alltogether.

Comment: [If you return from the main thread, does the process exit?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=13023) Also, do not ignore the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread): *"A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the `_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex` functions for thread management rather than `CreateThread` and `ExitThread`"*. You *are* using the CRT.